# How to use EmbeddedKsql in SpringBoot application?

Tags: ksqldb, confluent-platform

I have Kafka Streams java Application up and running. I was trying to use KSQL to create simple queries and Use Kafka Stream for complex solution. I wanted to run both KSQL and Kafka Streams as
Java application.

I was going to through https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/blob/master/ksqldb-examples/src/main/java/io/confluent/ksql/embedded/EmbeddedKsql.java. is there any documentation for EmbeddedKsql ? or any working prototype ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KsqlDb 0.10 has been launched and of the newest features in it is the Java Client.

Please go through - https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksqldb-0-10-0-latest-features-updates/

Answer (score 1):

The KsqlDB server does not have a supported Java API at this time. The project doesn't offer any guarantees of maintaining compatibility between releases.

If you were to run ksqlDB embedded in your Java application then `KsqlContext` would be the class to play around with. But I'm not sure how up-to-date it is, nor can I guarantee it won't be removed in a future release. I'm afraid there there aren't any documentation or examples to look at, as it's not a supported use.

The only supported way to communicate with ksqlDB is really through its HTTP endpoints.  You could still embed the server in your own Java app and talk locally of HTTP, though running them in separate JVMs has many benefits.